# Hanging paragraphs for entire document

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I want hanging paragraphs throughout my document. I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}\begin{hangparas}{15pt}{1}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{itemize}
    \item Something
    \item Something else
\end{itemize}

\lipsum[4-6]

\end{hangparas}\end{document}
```

But the paragraphs after the itemize environment fail to have the indentation pattern I wanted. Of course, I realize I could just start and stop the hanging indent every time I use another environment, but that would be rather annoying. So solutions that *don't* suggest doing that would be preferred. Ideally, I'd like to just put a single command in the preamble that impacts all the paragraphs in the document, but which still lets me use the itemize environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use TeX primitive solution of hanging paragraphs, i. e. positive `\leftskip` and negative `\parindent` then your problem does not occur.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\leftskip=15pt \parindent=-\leftskip

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{itemize}
    \item Something
    \item Something else
\end{itemize}

\lipsum[4-6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh this answer makes me very happy.

Answer (score 2):

You rather want a negative indentation (but the result is rather disputable).

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{-15pt}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-15pt}
\calclayout
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{7.5pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{itemize}
    \item Something
    \item Something else
\end{itemize}

\lipsum[4-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks great! I'll wait around and see if a better option comes up. I'm not sure what you mean by "the result is rather disputable". But if you're wondering why I'm doing this, the basic idea is to build a tex version of Stephen Mumford's 'Mumford Method' handout (see https://sites.google.com/site/stephendmumford/the-mumford-method).

Comment: @Shay I saw it, I'm waiting goosebumps to straighten off.

Comment: Ha! With that target in mind: how would you modify the answer you gave in order to make it more friendly to the multicol environment? This wasn't in my original question, so I'll not judge your answer by this criterion; mostly just curious.

Comment: (To be clear: I like your answer. And I can make it work with muticols by setting the \columsep length to whatever I need. But other users may want this and not know how to do that, so I'm wondering if you can see a way to make these two things get along better.)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to put your environment in a group. You can have it in a stroke for all itemize environments with `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\bgroup}
\AfterEndEnvironment{itemize}{\egroup}
\begin{document}

\begin{hangparas}{15pt}{1}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{itemize}
    \item Something
    \item Something else
\end{itemize}%

\lipsum[4-6]

 \end{hangparas}
```

[image]
    \end{document}

Comment: Well that's certainly an easy hack! I'm glad to know it. Should've tried it myself.